# Redux doesn't update state at the first time

Tags: reactjs, express, redux

Redux doesn't update state at the first time

I making a simple React app with Redux and Express as API, for study purposes. When the app make a post call to the API, I want to make a fetch call after it to update the list of items. So when I add the product at the first time, the fetch is called but the redux doestn't update the list with the new item in the database, but with the next insertion does!

Demostration:
[image]

Reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  list: [],
  product: {},
};

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PRODUCTS_FETCHED":
      return { ...state, list: action.list };
    case "PRODUCT_ADDED":
      return {
        ...state,
        product: action.product,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Actions:

```
import axios from "axios";
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:7000/products";

export function fetchProducts() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    await axios.get(BASE_URL).then((res) => {
      return dispatch({
        type: "PRODUCTS_FETCHED",
        list: res.data,
      });
    });
  };
}

export function addProduct(product) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    await axios.post(BASE_URL, product).then(dispatch(fetchProducts()));
    return {
      type: "PRODUCT_ADDED",
      product: product,
    };
  };
}
```

List component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProducts } from "../../store/actions/productsActions";
import Field from "../Field/Field";

import "./List.css";

function List() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.list);

  useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchProducts()), [dispatch]);
 
  return (
    <div className="List">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {products ? products.map((el, key) => {
            return (
              <tr key={key}>
                <th>{el.id}</th>
                <td>{el.name}</td>
                <td>{el.category}</td>
                <td>{el.quantity}</td>
                <td>${el.price}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          }): (
            <h1 id="loading">Loading...</h1>
          )}
          <Field />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Field component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Field.css";

import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addProduct } from "../../store/actions/productsActions";

import * as Yup from "yup";

function Field() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      category: "",
      quantity: 0,
      price: 0,
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      name: Yup.string().max(30, "Max lenght is 30!").required("Required!"),
      category: Yup.string().max(30, "Max lenght is 30!").required("Required!"),
      quantity: Yup.number().min(1, "None is invalid!").required("Required!"),
      price: Yup.number().min(1, "None is invalid!").required("Required!"),
    }),
    validateOnChange: false,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      const product = {
        name: values.name,
        category: values.category,
        quantity: values.quantity,
        price: values.price,
      };

      dispatch(addProduct(product))
    },
  });
  return (
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="name"
          name="name"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.name}
        ></input>
        {formik.errors.name && <p>{formik.errors.name}</p>}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="category"
          name="category"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.category}
        ></input>
        {formik.errors.category && <p>{formik.errors.category}</p>}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="quantity"
          name="quantity"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.quantity}
        ></input>
        {formik.errors.quantity && <p>{formik.errors.quantity}</p>}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="price"
          name="price"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.price}
        ></input>
        {formik.errors.price && <p>{formik.errors.price}</p>}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" onClick={formik.handleSubmit}>
          +
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default Field;
```

Comment: In which component do you do the fetching? Where is the request being made using the fetch api? Which function exactly causes this problem?

Comment: Why do you have a dispatch inside your Actions fetchProducts() return statement?

Comment: The fetching is done by axios in the fetchProducts action in action creator. Is it bad to call multiple actions inside another?